# Get SIP Protocol header information using PHP

Tags: php, sip

Is it possible to get header information for SIP protocol ..

to print it like

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP nm;branch=foo;received=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;rport=26810
From: <sip:nm@nm>;tag=root
To: <sip:nm2@nm2>;tag=as28384b45
Call-ID: 50000
CSeq: 42 OPTIONS
Server: FPBX-12.0.76.2(11.17.1)
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO ..
```

example for SIP response
 this website provide : https://www.shodan.io/search?query=fpbx

for example i try to fetch header data for HHTP and HHTPS using

```
print_r(get_headers("https://200.35.78.130/", 1));
```

is there anyway to get it for SIP ?